# GeoServer crashing when opening layer preview

Tags: geoserver, tomcat

My GeoServer crashes often producing the following error while try to open layer preview tab from the admin console.  I am working with sensitive data and I have an application using a GeoWebCache (GWC) layer, for the first four zoom levels the map is working fine, but after that it ends up with pink layers, I configured the service to use automatic GWC.

This is the bug report I am getting while opening the layer preview tab:

```
Oops, something went wrong...

Sorry, something unexpected happened on the server.

Here's an error report you can include in a JIRA bug report about this
issue:

org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Failed to add pluggable
    layergroup configuration panels at
                org.geoserver.web.data.layergroup.AbstractLayerGroupPage$4.populateItem(AbstractLayerGroupP age.java:213)
    at
    org.apache.wicket.markup.html.list.ListView.onPopulate(ListView.java:562)
    at
    org.apache.wicket.markup.repeater.AbstractRepeater.onBeforeRender(AbstractRepeater.java:131)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.internalBeforeRender(Component.java:1071) at
    org.apache.wicket.Component.beforeRender(Component.java:1105) at
    org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onBeforeRenderChildren(MarkupContainer.java:1753)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.onBeforeRender(Component.java:3946) at
    org.apache.wicket.markup.html.form.Form.onBeforeRender(Form.java:2056) at
    org.apache.wicket.Component.internalBeforeRender(Component.java:1071) at
    org.apache.wicket.Component.beforeRender(Component.java:1105) at
    org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.onBeforeRenderChildren(MarkupContainer.java:1753)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.onBeforeRender(Component.java:3946) at
    org.apache.wicket.Page.onBeforeRender(Page.java:1531) at
    org.apache.wicket.Component.internalBeforeRender(Component.java:1071) at
    org.apache.wicket.Component.beforeRender(Component.java:1105) at
    org.apache.wicket.Component.prepareForRender(Component.java:2292) at
    org.apache.wicket.Page.prepareForRender(Page.java:1521) at
    org.apache.wicket.Component.prepareForRender(Component.java:2329) at
    org.apache.wicket.Page.renderPage(Page.java:892) at
                org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.respond(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:261) at
        org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.respond(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:105) at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1258) at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1329) at
    org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1436) at
    org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545) at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:484) at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doGet(WicketServlet.java:138)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621) at
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) at
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(Servlet WrappingController.java:159)
    at
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722) at
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304) at
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) at
    org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:27) at
    org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) at
        org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:74) at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:45) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:49) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) at org.vfny.geoserver.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:68) at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116) at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:72) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:68) at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:72) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:68) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:72) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:115) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:68) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:72) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:68) at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:72) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173) at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:134) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:75) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:47) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:403) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProcessor.process(Http11NioProcessor.java:369) at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:317) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1532) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) at org.geoserver.web.data.layergroup.AbstractLayerGroupPage$4.populateItem(AbstractLayerGroupPage.java:210) ... 112 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.geoserver.wms.web.publish.LayerAuthoritiesAndIdentifiersPanel.<init>(LayerAuthoritiesAndIdentifiersPanel.java:47) at
     org.geoserver.wms.web.publish.WMSLayerGroupConfig.<init>(WMSLayerGroupConfig.java:23)
     ... 117 more>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue (java.lang.nullPointerException resulting in pink screen in layer preview), although I was not able to preview the layer at all.  The cause was that the layer store was configured without a workspace.  I was able to fix the problem by removing and rebuilding the layer store within a valid workspace.

See [this post](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Error-report-I-don-t-understand-td3789997.html) from the Geoserver mailing lists for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to change content language of your browser as English, that you use to open Geoserver Admin Page. Your problem will be fixed. If it continues, try to change your decimal seperator of your system.